# Grouping an array of object by a keyword in key

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects as follows

```
const data =   [
   {
      "id": 66,
      "Time": "2022-03-24 05:58:59",
      "Data": "1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 2 2 2",
   },
   {
      "id": 57,
      "Time": "2022-03-24 02:58:01",
      "Data": "2 3 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 11",
  },
  {
     "id": 65,
      "Time": "2022-03-23 23:58:01",
       "Data": "1 3 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1",
   },
   {
     "id": 59,
      "Time": "2022-03-23 21:59:01",
       "Data": "39 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2",
      },
    {
      "id": 42,
      "Time": "2022-03-23 06:35:20",
      "Data": "1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2",
   },
   {
      "id": 48,
      "Time": "2022-03-23 01:58:01",
      "Data": "2 3 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 11",
  },
  {
     "id": 35,
      "Time": "2022-03-22 23:58:01",
       "Data": "1 3 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1",
   },
   {
     "id": 59,
      "Time": "2022-03-22 20:59:01",
       "Data": "39 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 2",
      },
      ....................
```

So, the number 39 indicates that the data retrieval has started and it will be continue for some hours and then it will stop. When we see next 39, then it indicates that the process has stopped earlier. So we need to group the data when number 39 is listed until next 39. I am trying to group the data by separating the key in the data key. So I am trying to use 39 to separate the data and group that in this format. This is the output

```
const data = 
   {
    "1": [
        {
      "id": 66,
      "Time": "2022-03-24 05:58:59",
      "Data": "1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 2 2 2",
   },
   {
      "id": 57,
      "Time": "2022-03-24 02:58:01",
      "Data": "2 3 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 11",
  },
  {
     "id": 65,
      "Time": "2022-03-23 23:58:01",
       "Data": "1 3 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1",
   },
   {
     "id": 59,
      "Time": "2022-03-23 21:59:01",
       "Data": "39 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2",
      },
    ]
    "2": [ {
      "id": 42,
      "Time": "2022-03-23 06:35:20",
      "Data": "1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2",
   },
   {
      "id": 48,
      "Time": "2022-03-23 01:58:01",
      "Data": "2 3 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 11",
  },
  {
     "id": 35,
      "Time": "2022-03-22 23:58:01",
       "Data": "1 3 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1",
   },
   {
     "id": 59,
      "Time": "2022-03-22 20:59:01",
       "Data": "39 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 2",
      }]
     ..........
```

I used lodash groupby to separate the data but not been able to grab the data. This is what I did

```
   const grouped =_.groupBy(data, item => item.Data.split('39').length-1);
```

Any idea will be greatful

Comment: Do you want to group them by the first number occuring in the `Data` prop? Please be more precise on how you want to group them. The question is unclear. Tell what rule an object has to fullfill to be put in one and not in another group.

Comment: Yes if the first number on data is 39, then group it before another number 39 comes

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: I still don't understand your question. Why do you want to do that? Can you please edit the question and provide your use case and some more description?

Comment: Why are you grouping by the length-1? You're basically grouping by the number of repetitions of `39` in the data.

Comment: @SilvanBregy, So, the number 39 indicates that the data retrieval has started and it will continue for some hours and then it will stop. When we see the next 39, then it indicates that the process has stopped earlier. So we need to group the data when number 39 is listed until next 39.

Comment: Okay. So when 39 occurs the data is put in a group until next 39 occurs. But does 39 behave like a separator OR do you only want to capture the data between two 39's ? And how do you get this data, is that a stream or do you group the data later on after you received this big array? I help you after answering this last question. '

Comment: @SilvanBregy, yes the 39 is the separator and it is coming from a JSON. When the process starts it put 39 in the data as starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you will change rule frequency,so i suggest you make rule as "callback function" to control your id

```js
function Groupz(arr=[],idcondition=(a,b)=>b){
    var l=arr.length;
    var obj_rs={};
    for(var i=0,j=1;i<l;i++){
        if(!(j in obj_rs)){
            obj_rs[j]=[];
        }
        obj_rs[j].push(arr[i]);
        j=idcondition(arr[i].Data,j)
    }
    return obj_rs;
}
var data=   [
   {
  "id": 66,
  "Time": "2022-03-24 05:58:59",
  "Data": "1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 2 2 2",
   },
   {
  "id": 57,
  "Time": "2022-03-24 02:58:01",
  "Data": "2 3 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 11",
  },
  {
 "id": 65,
  "Time": "2022-03-23 23:58:01",
   "Data": "1 3 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1",
   },
   {
 "id": 59,
  "Time": "2022-03-23 21:59:01",
   "Data": "39 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2",
  },
{
  "id": 42,
  "Time": "2022-03-23 06:35:20",
  "Data": "1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2",
   },
   {
  "id": 48,
  "Time": "2022-03-23 01:58:01",
  "Data": "2 3 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 11",
  },
  {
 "id": 35,
  "Time": "2022-03-22 23:58:01",
   "Data": "1 3 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1",
   },
   {
 "id": 59,
  "Time": "2022-03-22 20:59:01",
   "Data": "39 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 2",
  },]
var final_group=Groupz(data,function(a,b){
    //Remove mutiple space,reduce to 1 space then split by single space
    var numbers=a.replace(/ +(?= )/g,'').split(' ');
    var l=numbers.length;
    /*
    //If you want check all number using this to loop all numbers to check whether 39 in string not only check first place
    for(var i=0;i<l;i++){
        if(numbers[i]=="39"){
            return b+1;
        }
    }
    
    return b;*/
    return b+!!(numbers.length>1&&numbers[0]=="39");
})

console.log(final_group);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `groubBy` function expects a key OR a function returning a key, to know where to put a given element. What you did is to put all elements who did have a `39` within one group and all elements not containing any `39` in another group.

Grouping the data using `groupBy`

```js
const data = [
    {
        "id": 66,
        "Time": "2022-03-24 05:58:59",
        "Data": "1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 2 2 2",
    },
    {
        "id": 57,
        "Time": "2022-03-24 02:58:01",
        "Data": "2 3 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 11",
    },
    {
        "id": 65,
        "Time": "2022-03-23 23:58:01",
        "Data": "1 3 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1",
    },
    {
        "id": 59,
        "Time": "2022-03-23 21:59:01",
        "Data": "39 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2",
    },
    {
        "id": 42,
        "Time": "2022-03-23 06:35:20",
        "Data": "1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2",
    },
    {
        "id": 48,
        "Time": "2022-03-23 01:58:01",
        "Data": "39 3 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 11",
    },
    {
        "id": 35,
        "Time": "2022-03-22 23:58:01",
        "Data": "1 3 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1",
    }

]

// keep track of the group. 
let groupKey = 0

const grouped = groupBy(data, element => {

    // increment the group as one element is found.
    if (element.Data.indexOf('39') > -1) {
        groupKey++
    }

    return groupKey 
})

console.log(grouped)

Object.keys(grouped).forEach(k => {
    console.log('group key:', k, 'element count:', grouped[k].length)
})
```

Note if the first element contains a `39` the resulting groups will start with `1` and else with `0`. So make sure the first element will **always hold** `39` OR make sure it will **always not hold** `39`. Ensure that it is consistent.

Feel free to leave a comment if you have any questions.

Comment: That's perfect but if the first element consists of a 39, then it will also be in the same group and should be included. Currently it excludes the array which has first element as 39